# timer signal the process that adds it and wakes it up from interruptable sleep

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am learning Linux device drivers and particularly timers and wait queues.
I want them to work together in a single character driver where I can put the driver to sleep using IO control command while I continue to get fasync interrupts in the user land using timer. 
I noticed that if I use

```
wait_event_interruptible();
```

then when the timer is expired, the driver comes out of wait with return code -512, even though the condition is not yet satisfied. But if I use

```
wait_event();
```

then the problem is solved. I read that wake_up_event_interruptible()
returns non-zero return code if interrupt wakes up the process.

is my understanding right that timer interrupts the process that adds it (I can not find any evidence of this in texts) as from my understanding timer function becomes independent of the state of process that added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [code for wait_event_interruptible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894113/code-for-wait-event-interruptible) : the function `wake_up_event_interruptible()` returns `-ERESTARTSYS` (ie. -512) when a signal is pending for the current kernel process.

Kernel timer (added with `setup_timer`) interrupts the execution of the current kernel process independent of it's state. To be more specific, from [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596000081/ch06s04.html), kernel has three queues: task queues, tasklets (as of kernel 2.3.43), and kernel timers. (In simple words) when a kernel timer expires, the CPU branches to an interrupt handling routine, which saves the current context and branches to timer registered callback function. After the interrupt is handled, the scheduler decides which task gets CPU to run.

Comment: So this means that my driver process, which is the one setting the interrupt, gets interrupted becuse my system is not busy and the driver is mostly running as current process and as timer generates an interrupt on expiring, my current process [in this case my driver] gets interrupted ? If I want my current code to work then is there a way other than again going in wait if return is other than 0 using while or something ? I mean is there a neater way ?

Comment: Not the driver process get's interrupted, the CPU gets interrupted. Your driver process may be interrupted, may be not. On a machine with 2 CPUs you driver process and timer interrupt handler may run together simultaneously, at the same time, even with different speeds. You need to take that into account when designing your driver. If your interrupt handler uses a shared resource which get's used in your other routines, you need to implement semaphores/mutexes so race conditions does not occur.